# YesMail v2 API: 400 Error with cURL request with PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

I am trying to GET targeting from an MMID but am returning the following error. I know my credentials are correct and have combed over the documentation several times. "appTesting" in the response below is the name of my App in YesMail

```
INFO: HTTP Response Code was: 400 INFO: Response Follows... HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Api-User: appTesting Content-Type: application/json Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 21:38:54 GMT Tracking-Id: f257bd75-47bb-40e7-a12c-5a45a042cbac X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff transfer-encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive {"status":400,"message":"Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target DataSource for lookup key [appTesting]"}
```

I kind of stumped. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$mmid = 'mmid';
$api_user = "appTesting";
$api_key = "api key";

$ym_api_url = 'https://api.yesmail.com/v2/masters/';

$curl_hdl = curl_init();

$curl_options = array(
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,           
CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,               
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Api-User: $api_user", "Api-Key: $api_key", "Accept: application/json",),
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,   
CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS, 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,     
CURLOPT_URL => $ym_api_url.$mmid.'/target',        
);

curl_setopt_array($curl_hdl, $curl_options);

$response = curl_exec($curl_hdl);

$http_response_code = curl_getinfo($curl_hdl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl_hdl);

echo PHP_EOL . "INFO: HTTP Response Code was: " . $http_response_code . PHP_EOL;

if ( $response === false )
{
echo PHP_EOL . "ERROR: curl_exec() has failed." . PHP_EOL;
}
else
{
echo PHP_EOL . "INFO: Response Follows..." . PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL . $response;
}
echo "<br/><br/>API USER: ".$api_user."<br/><br/>API KEY: ".$api_key;
?>
```